# jackson serializer throw NullPointerException when disable annotation

Tags: java, annotations, jackson, serialization

```
 objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false);
```

I use code above to disable annotations, but when runs to

```
 protected void _addMixUnders(Method src, AnnotatedMethod target)
{
    for (Annotation a : src.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
        if (_annotationIntrospector.isHandled(a)) {
            target.addIfNotPresent(a);
        }
    }
}
```

in AnnotatedClass, _annotationIntrospector is null so it throws NullPointerException.
What should I do ? thanks.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMixUnders(AnnotatedClass.java:974)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:637)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:413)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.classWithCreators(BasicClassIntrospector.java:185)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:157)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:96)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:973)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:251)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:758)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:380)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.resolve(BeanSerializerBase.java:307)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.SerializerCache.addAndResolveNonTypedSerializer(SerializerCache.java:159)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:744)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:420)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:601)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2575)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2097)
```

Comment: What version of Jackson? What are you trying to serialize?

Comment: serialize a class with a field of type enum using jackson 1.9.13. If there is no enum field, serializing is ok.

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example along with the exception stack trace you get.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  I found all enum field implement an interface with a function marked with JsonValue, I remove the annotation serializer is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 3 years late, but for future generations, here is what worked for me:

```
// Don't use this:
// objectMapper.disable(SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
// Use this instead:
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.nopInstance());
```

This worked for me in 1.9.13-atlassian-1.